# MySQL loads CSV file but without double quotes?

Tags: mysql, csv, load, quotes

I am using MySQL to load a CSV file, but there is no quotes for the string column, so I only get the first letter of the value.

```
1,Toyota Park,Bridgeview,IL,0
2,Columbus Crew Stadium,Columbus,OH,0
3,RFK Stadium,Washington,DC,0
```

After I use the code here, I got this:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\Users\\tank\\Desktop\\test.csv'
INTO TABLE test
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 0 ROWS;
```

and I had this table:

```
+---------------------------------------------+
| ID, Studios, City, State, Open              |
+---------------------------------------------+
| '1', 'T', 'B', 'I', '0'                     |
| '2', 'C', 'C', 'O', '0'                     |
| '3', 'R', 'W', 'D', '0'                     |
+---------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Now it's time to go back to your data source and get a proper export.  If you have whitespace in your column values, then you should escape those columns with double quotes (or some other delimiter).

Answer (score 2):

You should use enclosed by:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\Users\\tank\\Desktop\\test.csv'
INTO TABLE test
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
ENCLOSED BY '\"'
ESCAPED BY '\"'
IGNORE 0 ROWS;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I find the reason, When I created the table, I used the syntax ```char``` not ```varchar(20)```, so it truncated to only keep the first letter. When there is no quotes in the csv file, Mysql would automatically enclosed them by a comma.